# How to know the margins settings used within a document?

Tags: margins

I know the package geometry and its 'showframe' option, so I know how to displayed the frames and the margins within a document. But I've no idea of the settings used to produced them.

Is there a way to know the size of each frame and each margin displayed with such an option ?
It would be useful to slightly adjust the frames and to compare two documents.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you are looking for. What about [`layout`](https://ctan.org/pkg/layout)?

Comment: frame show your settings. if you not define margins, than it use default value (`margin=1in`, i suppose);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `layouts` package which enables the display of several aspects of a document such as page layout dimensions, paragraphs, floats, etc. For instance:

```
\usepackage{layouts}
...
\begin{document}
...
\begin{figure}
\currentpage
\oddpagelayouttrue
\pagedesign
\caption{Odd page layout for this document}
\end{figure}
...
\end{document}
```

will produce a figure showing the layout of the current (odd) page and listing all the values of the layout parameters such as `\oddsidemargin`, `\textwidth`, `page width` and so on.

The package also lets you try out what different layouts will look like if you were  to change any dimensions, thus in one document you could compare different layouts.

Comment: Thank you very much ! :-)